# Oracle Add a new member function/procedure to an object type

Tags: oracle, object, addition, member, procedure

I am trying to do the following; let's say I have created an object type in Oracle

```
create type test as object(
name varchar2(12),
member procedure print1);
/
create type body test is
member procedure print1 is
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Test');
end print1;
end;
/
```

Now I want to add a new member procedure print2 - again, I can do that by typing:

```
alter type test
add member procedure print2 cascade;
```

Now, my question is: how do I just define the body and add print2 without repeating other definitions? I know I can do a create or replace body test and list implementations for both procedures, but this is not practical as I have to maintain code for object types that others wrote and I have no idea how they implemented the code, just that these procedures and functions exist.

I have been through the documentation and the web, but could not find an answer and it seems silly to me that Oracle would expect the developer to type all the definitions again.

Regards,
George

Comment: Can you get the current type body from user_source?

Comment: Sure, but what difference would that make?

Comment: If you have the source, do you need to know "how they implemented the code"?  Can't you just copy and paste the entire thing, and add your new procedure to the end?

Comment: Possibly, if you spend a couple of days. The table is quite long and involves a lot of cursors and other user-defined objects. Is there a way to avoid that and simply say here is the new specification, bundle it together with the previous ones?

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle SQL Developer to change the type body.

Or use any text editor to change the source file and run it in your favorite SQL prompt.

Object types are the most advanced programming concept in Oracle. Maybe you'd be better off with standalone functions?

However, I understand your point. AFAIK the type body cannot contain functions that are not listed in the specification. The order of the methods shouldn't matter either, so there seems to be no reason not to have this option.

Comment: I haven't got the source code. Also, would it not make sense if there was an alter type body add member procedure command? I know that the type body is not allowed anything not listed in the specification, I am just asking that like you can add stuff with alter to the specification, can you do the same thing with body?

Comment: If you have the privileges to change the type specification, you do have access to the body source. You just can't change it in the same way as with the specification. It seems they (Oracle) "forgot" to provide this option.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a procedure that dynamically adds a definition to a type:

```
create or replace procedure add_procedure(p_new_procedure_definition varchar2)
    authid current_user
is
    v_object_type_body varchar2(32767) := 'create or replace ';
begin
    --Build string with current definitions
    for source_code in
    (
        select text
        from user_source
        where name = 'TEST'
            and type = 'TYPE BODY'
        order by line
    ) loop
        --Don't include the last "END;" yet.
        --(Huge assumption that the package ends with "END;")
        if replace(upper(trim(source_code.text)),chr(10)) <> 'END;' then
            v_object_type_body := v_object_type_body||source_code.text;
        end if;
    end loop;

    --Add new definition    
    v_object_type_body := v_object_type_body||chr(10)||
        p_new_procedure_definition||chr(10)||'end;';

    --For debugging
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_object_type_body);

    --Compile the type
    execute immediate v_object_type_body;
end;
/
```

Then run it like this:

```
begin
    add_procedure(
    '
    member procedure print2 is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line(''Test2'');
    end print2;
    '
    );
end;
/
```

Although you need to make some pretty big assumptions about how the package will end.  To make this a truly generic solution you'd need to build a PL/SQL parser, which is basically impossible.  And the procedure will only work with 32K, if the types are very large you'll probably need to use CLOBs.

Comment: This is really great! But how would I change (and drop) the procedure now? ...And how do I go about different signatures? :)

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do that.  There is a DROP option, but like with ADD, it only applies to the spec.  I think the real solution to this problem is "don't do this".